# Add date column with null values into Share point List using Python

Tags: python, pandas, sharepoint

I have a list with a date column and a excel sheet with date column along with some empty values in it. Now I need to add the excel column data into share point List using Client credentials .

```
    sp_list ="Samplelist"       
    sp_lists = ctx.web.lists
    s_list = sp_lists.get_by_title(sp_list) 
    x=pd.read_excel('ExcelBook.xlsx')
    for i in range(len(x['Name'])):
        item_to_create = s_list.add_item({"Title": x["Name"][i],
                                         "Date":str(x["Date"])
                                        }).executequery()
```

ERROR: `Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.DateTime'. See the inner exception for more details.`, `400 Client Error: Bad Request for url`

This code works fine if there are no null values in the excel column, However I have null values in excel Sheet and I want to update the share point list with excel content.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: try converting date with YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00Z format